# Make 2 columns from 2 different tables unique in sql

Tags: sql

I have a database having many tables and I want to make 2 columns from 2 different tables unique.
For example, 1 table named person contains fields like id, name,father_name,date of birth, res. address etc and other table named institute contains id (which is foreign key of id of person table), institute.
I have to make a combination of (name,father_name,date of birth, institute) unique. Can anybody help me??

Comment: Please add example data and expected output to make it more clear

Comment: You can do it.  In most databases, you would need a trigger or user-defined function to enforce a multi-table constraint.

Comment: An indexed view can have a unique constraint, so this would do it (but depends on your database type).  Another solution would be to create a third table that holds values from your two base tables and add the constraint there.

Comment: please specify the dbms type (vendor) and version - do this always - it often does make a difference to the answer

Comment: make unique? Delete doublettes? Display only uniques? Display doublettes? Pleas specify your question?